# Disable Nextgen lightbox effect for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How can I disable the lightbox effect on the nextgen wordpress plugin when viewed on mobile device?

Here is the project: www.brendanbrowne.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

Please bare in mind that you'd need jQuery 1.9.1 or less because as far as I'm aware 1.9.1 and lower still have jQuery browser with(allbeit deprecated). If you are using jQuery 2.0 you'll need to download jQuery browser as a plugin.

```
var isiPad = /ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
if (isiPad)
{
    $('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail a').removeAttr('rel');
}

if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
    $('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail a').removeAttr('rel');
    //alert('You are using a mobile device!');
}
```